# Can two viewcontrollers share the same uiwebview?

Tags: objective-c, webview

I have two view controllers. I´m wondering if the can share the same UIWebView, so that when a link is clicked in one view controllers, the result is shown in the other? If so, how can I implement that?

Comment: Not at the same time. A view can only have one parent. So you can't show the same view in to different view controllers at the same time.

Comment: Not at the same time. I have a login form populated in the first viewcontrollers webview. When the user submits, I want him to see the resulted website in the second viewcontrollers webview.

Comment: How are the two view controllers related? Segue push in a NavigationController? Part of a SplitViewController on an iPad? You might be able to get what you want not by sharing the UIWebView, but by passing the URL from one VC to the other via a segue or something.

Comment: They are connected via a modal segue from the submit button. How can I pass the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's certainly possible to do, but not necessarily a good idea.  If you change the web view's parent view at the wrong time your transition between view controllers might look very funny.  You want to change it somewhere between your first view controller's viewDidDisappear and your second's viewWillAppear, I think.  But it might be tricky.

That said, if you really want to move the web view to a new view controller something like this will work:

```
[theViewControllerThatShouldHaveTheWebViewNow.view addSubview:theWebView];
```

or you could even assign `theViewControllerThatShouldHaveTheWebViewNow`'s `view` property to `theWebView`, but changing a view controller's root view on the fly will probably lead to some aggravating behaviors.